# Backup failed because The dump process failed with exitcode 2

Tags: laravel, database-backups

How to solve this error I'm using the [spatie](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-backup) laravel backup package for laravel 8.12

```
Backup failed because The dump process failed with exitcode 2 : Misuse of shell builtins : mysqldump: Got error: 2004: "Can't create TCP/IP socket (10106 "Unknown error")" when trying to connect
```

controller code:

```
public function create()
    {
          try {
              \Artisan::call('backup:run' ,['--only-db' => true]);
               $output = \Artisan::output();
               Log::info("Backpack\BackupManager -- new backup started \r\n" . $output);
               session()->flash('success', 'Successfully created backup!');
               return redirect()->back();
          } catch (Exception $e) {
               session()->flash('danger', $e->getMessage());
               return redirect()->back();
          }
    }
```

Comment: Yes my project is live and working

Comment: oh did you try `backup:run` only without `--only-db`?

Comment: I tried `backup:run` and I have alsoe this error `Backup failed because The dump process failed with exitcode 2 : Misuse of shell builtins : mysqldump: Got error: 2004: "Can't create TCP/IP socket (10106 "Unknown error")" when trying to connect
`

Comment: laravel 8 PHP version: 7.3.4

Comment: not php mysql i m asking

Comment: Works correctly with this command `php artisan backup:run --only-db`

Comment: Server version: 10.1.38-MariaDB